# Повесить команду на событие

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно повесить команду (`ICommand`) из ViewModel на событие `Window.Closed`? Ради соблюдения принципов MVVM не хочется пользоваться обычным обработчиком.

Comment: Принципы MVVM всего лишь разделяют кто и что делает. Они не запрещают использовать code-behind вида для нужд вида.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться такого. В MVVM вью-модель должна управлять видимостью. Перепроверьте свой дизайн.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `EventTrigger` в сочетании с `InvokeCommandAction` из неймспейса `Windows.Interactivity`:

```
<Window ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowClosedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```