# Подписка на событие по правилам MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Мне нужно подписаться на событие так, что бы обработчик события был во `ViewModel`. И при этом не нарушая паттерн MVVM. Что мне прописать в свойство в `xaml` что бы обработчик брался из **ViewModel**, что-то наподобие **`Command`** у кнопки, но для других элементов, например `TextBox`?

### View:

```
    <TextBox
 TextChanged="Вот тут как подписаться по правилам MVVM"
 FontSize="24"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Height="42"
 Margin="184,100,0,0"
 TextWrapping="Wrap"
 Text="{Binding Name}"
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Width="176"/>
```

Comment: А если просто в Set свойства вызывать необходимую логику?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А где я должен это сделать? В модели или во вьюмодели?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну вот если без MVVM то вот так `private void TextChanged(...){Тут логика}` но мне это не подходит

Comment: Когда вы привязываете свойство к TextBlock - это свойство будет автоматически обновляться при изменение значения в View, вам лишь достаточно будет там, где у вас `OnPropertyChanged("Name");` реализовать необходимое обновление модели, тут не обязательно подписываться на событие обновления. Это если по простому пойти конечно. Чуть сложнее способ - это использовать `InvokeCommandAction`, например как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514658/220553), так вы подписываетесь на событие и используете приемлемые для MVVM команды.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ И да у меня не TextBlock а TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще бывает два вида реализации MVVM - "Строгий" и "Нестрогий"?
При строгом следовании паттерну MVVM все события должны быть реализованы с помощью механизма команд, так View становиться практически полностью освобождена от программной логики, ну это так, отступление...

Теперь варианты обновления:

1. **Использование свойств** - При привязке свойства к объекту представления (скажем TextBox как в вашем случае) оно автоматически будет подхватывать все изменения, производимые с ним во View. Тем самым мы смело можем добавить свою логику в `set` привязанного свойства, например как это сделано у вас, строка `user.name = value;`. Но я не советую нагружать свойства какой то серьезной логикой.
2. **Использование InvokeCommandAction** - В этом варианте мы обрабатываем необходимое нам событие, но только реализуем его с помощью команд. Для этого нужно подключить System.Windows.Interactivity, реализовать команду с необходимой логикой и далее написать что то вроде:

   ```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">          
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </TextBox>
   ```

Помните, что MVVM это просто паттерн, следовать ему, следовать строго или не следовать вовсе - выбор каждого. Думайте об удобстве и удобстве ваших пользователей в первую очередь.

Comment: А откуда мне взять `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`? Как мне подключить неймспейс к xaml?
`

Comment: @SeeSharp https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/220553

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvJwR.png

Comment: @SeeSharp Вы должны сначала подключить библиотеку через Referense (ссылки), далее в XAML прописать `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` (у меня это сделал ReSharper) и далее весь предоставленный мной код должен успешно заработать.

Comment: Извините за шум который поднял вокруг вопроса. Был растерян, искал какой-либо рабочий вариант и не смотрел на его "гибкость".  Далее понял что ваш ответ мне подходит, почему-то вопрос та в том как подписаться на событие, а не как обновлять свойство. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы значение обновлялось при вводе во View в привязке нужно использовать:
**UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**

```
 <TextBox
 FontSize="24"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Height="42"
 Margin="184,100,0,0"
 TextWrapping="Wrap"
 Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Width="176"/>
```

Обязательно реализовывать интерфейс **INotifyPropertyChanged** в VM.

Comment: INPC не нужен. Его задача наоборот оповещать View при изменениях свойства через код. То есть ViewModel -> View - да, нужен. View -> ViewModel - нет. Также `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` - это довольно странное решение. Поясню: Представим что у нас Model это база, вы задали в свойстве Set обновление значения в базе запросом. Теперь мы ставим `PropertyChanged` и что будет? При написание слова `Привет` вы сделаете ~5 запросов в базу (П р и в е т), как то это не очень хорошо, вам не кажется? Изначально `UpdateSourceTrigger` стоит в значение, которое обновит свойство при потере фокуса.

Comment: И это как по мне самый лучший вариант для обновления "Модели", ибо модель не стоит дергать по пустякам. Так что все, что вы написали тут совсем не обязательно и я черт побери не понимаю логику автора вопроса....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ логика по моему проста. Мне нужно что бы введенное значение сразу обновляло переменную через VM. Можно было бы через code-behind, но у меня класс создан в VM и мне потом нужно с ним работать. Для этого пол проекта переписывать пришлось бы

Comment: @SeeSharp Во первых об этом способе я вам написал сразу, я вам говорил что при привязке данные автоматически будут изменены у привязанного свойства, хотите что то менять в Model - задайте в Set указанного свойства нужную логику. Писал? Да. Во вторых, я вам дал альтернативу на вопрос `TextChanged="Вот тут как подписаться по правилам MVVM"`, то есть я вам расписал как по правилам MVVM идет подпись на события. И тут появляется ответ, который повторяет то, что я вам говорил, советует неверные вещи и в итоге это принимают, извините, я это понять не могу.

Comment: @SeeSharp если ваш вопрос был про "Как обновлять свойство моментально при изменение его в View", то мы смело можем это закрывать как дубликат, например на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/593514/220553). Тогда от меня вам минус за не точно поставленный вопрос, сойдет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вы правы. Голосуйте за закрытие, действительно дубликат. Вы извините, что не так поставил вопрос, и не увидел ваш ответ сразу.