# WinUI 3 MVVM Toolkit как в Command указать тип евента?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-app-sdk

Только начал изучать WinUi и C#, подскажите как сделать событие типа DoubleTapped на StackPanel в DataTemplate и как его подружить с RelayCommand. И как в Command можно указать тип события?

XAML

```
<Window
    x:Class="App2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:TestViewModel x:Name="TestViewModel"/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        
        <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       Margin="20,0,20,8"
                       FontSize="24" 
                       FontStyle="Italic" 
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Foreground="DarkBlue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       Margin="20,0,20,8"
                       FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="DarkGray" 
                       Opacity="0.8" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Click me!"
        Command="{x:Bind TestViewModel.AddItemCommand}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace App2
{
    public class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Item> _items { get; set; }

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            AddItemCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem);

            _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            _items.Add(new Item(0, "000"));
            _items.Add(new Item(1, "111"));
            _items.Add(new Item(2, "222"));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get => _items;

        }

        public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; }
        private void AddItem() => _items.Add(new Item(8, "888"));
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Item() { }
        public Item(int id, string name) { Id = id; Name = name; }
    }
}
```

Может неправильно ещё излагаю мысль, программировать начал совсем недавно. Нужно сделать нечто такое: StackPanel DoubleTapped="StackPanel_DoubleTapped" только как это сделать это в вьюмодели ума не приложу.

Comment: Извиняюсь, наделал кучу и запутался в них. Обновил и проверил.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/917223/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там WPF, здесь немного другое.

Comment: В общем-то @EvgeniyZ дал почти правильную подсказку. [Есть такая либа и для WinUI3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed). Правда отличие в использовании там есть: [хороший пример, как раз Вашего случая есть тут](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/InvokeCommandAction). Суть выйдет та же: ставите Behavior на событие и ставите Action на вызов ICommand.

Comment: Хотя, я бы лично сделал бы как @aepot предложил и не парился. Зачастую всё равно конкретная View привязана к конкретной ViewModel. Плюс сами майки в своих примерах для UWP/WinUI частенько делают ViewModel - свойством View, чтобы потом x:bind добавлять. Так что доступ к ViewModel из View зачастую и так имеется.

Comment: @John `Есть такая либа и для WinUI3` там WinUI2/UWP, не путайте. Там последний коммит октябрь 2020, Windows App SDK тогда еще даже не было в природе. 1:1 :)

Comment: @aepot Если полазить по комментариям (например [этот](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/issues/192#issuecomment-675506603), [этот](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/issues/225#issuecomment-1009791985)), да и посмотреть последнюю версию на том же NuGet (которой 3 месяца), то можно заметить, что поддержка WinUI 3 всеж вроде как есть. Конечно, может что путаю, но стоит попробовать.

Comment: Всё разобрался, всем огромное спасибо и за ссылки, и за пример.

Comment: Решение из ответа зашло или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормальных способов на чистом XAML это сделать я пока не нашел, но можно вот так:

```xml
<ListView DoubleTapped="ListView_DoubleTapped"/>
```

Кодбихайнд

```cs
public void ListView_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object item = ((Selector)sender).SelectedItem;
    ICommand command = TestViewModel.AddItemCommand;
    if (command.CanExecute(item))
        command.Execute(item);
}
```

Еще поищу решения, как время будет. Пока, к сожалению, такой возможности нет.

Comment: Это то понятно, вопрос как это всунутъ в шаблон MVVM и Command/RelayCommand.

Comment: @PavelLaek так я и вызываю вам RelayCommand передавая в него данные элемента, который был кликнут. Все по канону, костыли живут внутри View, MVVM в целости и сохранности. С точки зрения MVVM вьюмодель ничего не должна знать о View, она как бы здесь ничего нового и не узнает.

Comment: Можно же было привязываемое поведение описать.