# Какой тип используют объекты xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне понять, какой тип ожидается у объектов в xaml?
У меня есть следующая строка:

```
<my:PdfDocumentViewer Width="800" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" Name="pdfDocumentViewer1" PdfLoaded=""></my:PdfDocumentViewer>
```

Как мне понять, какой объект привязывать к PdfLoaded?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Вам студия должна предложить создать новое событие, согласитесь и она сама вам сгенерирует нужное, а там просто поправьте имя или банально посмотрите что и как. Ну а если надо посмотреть, то в C# коде напишите в любом месте `var doc = new PdfDocumentViewer(); doc.Нужное` и смотрите что там за тип и что он требует.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Подскажите пожалуйста, а я могу как-то вызвать объект PdfDocumentViewer, который создаю в xaml?
Проблема в том, что у меня есть два класса ScheduleTypeViewModel.cs и ScheduleTypeView.xaml.cs, в котором могу прописать команду this.pdfDocumentViewer1.LoadFromFile(path), но в ScheduleTypeViewModel.cs у меня нет этого объекта. Уже целый день сижу ломаю голову, как его получить

Comment: По правилам MVVM (а судя по названиям вида `...ViewModel` вы им придерживаетесь), вы не можете, да и не должны хотеть использовать что-либо из View слоя (UI) в C# коде, у вас должно быть строгое разграничение всего на малосвязанные слои. И тут все зависит от контрола, который вы используете, его возможностей. Допустим у некоторых есть и MVVM вариант, и события, например, простая кнопка (`Button`), вы можете написать `<Button Click="...">` и использовать по старинке события (нарушение MVVM), либо вы можете написать `<Button Command="{Binding ...}">` и вот вам уже MVVM команды.

Comment: Поэтому анализируйте используемый вами компонент и смотрите как с ним взаимодействовать. Допустим старые события можно [привязать к командам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/917223/220553), будет вам все по правилам MVVM. Либо вы можете сделать обертку, или внедряемые свойства, которые будут нужное вам отдавать VM слою без нарушений MVVM. Ну а если вы не используете MVVM, то просто задайте имя (вы его уже задали - `pdfDocumentViewer1`) и используйте его потом в коде окна.

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное! Сейчас буду смотреть какие события отвечают за просмотр pdf